# How to check availablity of file descriptor in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, file, sockets, io

Using `ulimit`, number of file descriptors can be set in a linux system. `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` also provides maximum fds.

Suppose there is some value for the number of `fds` has been set in the system. I am doing some socket programming and I am accepting multiple connections from the client.

Each accept call will use one fd. If number of clients trying to connect exceeds the number of maximum limit of the fds, the error throws "too many open files".

**Is there a way to check whether the fd is available before calling accept system call ??**

Comment: I don't get the _"If number of clients trying to connect exeeds the number of maximum limit of the fds, the error throws "too many open files""_: no error is thrown, only `accept()` returns -1 and `errno` is set to `ENFILE`. This is _the_ way to detect the situation, and the program can continue to execute and handle the erronous situation.

Comment: Don't try to predict errors. Handle them as they arise. You can't know how many pending connections there are either, so you cannot predict  whether an `accept()` will fail at all.

Comment: Suppose the linux has fd_max = 20. maximum number of fds are 20. and 30 clients are trying to connect at the same time. So, here 20 successful connections would be established and the rest will throw error as "too many open file descriptors"

Comment: That's correct. Your point? NB Errors are returned. Exceptions are thrown. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @SKM *Suppose the linux has fd_max = 20. maximum number of fds are 20. and 30 clients are trying to connect at the same time. So, here 20 successful connections would be established and the rest will throw error as "too many open file descriptors"*  So **what would you do in that situation**?  Kill existing connections?  If you're not going to do that, what's the point of even trying to predict that `accept()` *might* fail?

Comment: @Andrew I have one application which goes in a loop when all the fds are exhausted and the cpu utilization is high during the time. fds are exhausted when number of client connections are huge. Hence in my case I want to check if any fd is available before accepting the connection and if it is not available, my server will simply close the connections and the subsequent client would be notified that connection has been reset.

Comment: @SKM So you're going to deliberately break a working connection just to try to make a new one? When your server gets busy, you'll kill existing connections to create new ones, which then get killed because there are even more incoming connections?  And thus make your server spin, killing connections so no one can actually get something useful done with their connection?  And to do all this, you're going to write a bunch of code that you then have to debug and maintain?

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the explanation. client sends SYN and server sends SYN/ACK in response and then client acknowledges with ACK and then connection is established. Then accept is called for data communication. If the fds are exhausted, accept will fail. But client had already received ACK. Hence client will never get to know that why the communication failed. If some TCP flag is set or reset because of accept failure, then client will get some information which is really dependent on OS. Hence I want to close the connections from the appication when this edge/rare condition occures.

Comment: So I think client can be notified with connection reset and again all the clients will try to connect. This may be a bit insane behaviour, but the client will get to know the connection limit and will get a chance to verify it.